# Negative exponents using the BigInteger class

Tags: java, biginteger

I'm doing some maths using the Java BigInteger class but getting an error when I'm trying to use a negative number as an exponent. Am I right in thinking that you can rearrange:

```
b · φ(N)^−1 mod N
```

as:

```
      b
------------
φ(N)^1 mod N
```

If not how can I rearrange the expression as to not get a negative exponent error in my Java code?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming, but about solving a math problem

Comment: No, you are not right in thinking so. See Sweeper's answer.

Comment: @ernest_k: I think it *is* a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BigInteger` can't have negative exponents, because that would make it a fraction (1 over something), which is not an "integer".

Try using `BigDecimal` instead.

As for your rearrangement of the expression, it should be rearranged like this:

```
      b
------------  mod N
   φ(N)^1
```

Comment: Assuming `^` means "exponent" here, not "xor", you can omit the `^1` part.

Comment: What's supposed to be the operator precedence between `mod` and `*`?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I know, it's just for clarity to show that there is a positive exponent.

Comment: While technically correct this answer doesn't really get to the heart of OPs mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Arithmetic mod N must be performed with modified rules. In particular inverses must be calculated much differently. The basic axiom of the inverse holds true:

> x * x<sup>-1</sup> = 1 mod N.

but you cannot compute x<sup>-1</sup> mod N by computing 1/x as a floating point or decimal value. Instead, you must use an algorithm specifically for this purpose. Usually a variant of the [extended euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers) is used.

Conveniently, Java's [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class already includes this algorithm for you: [`modInverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modInverse-java.math.BigInteger-). So your calculation should look something like:

```
BigInteger phi = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
BigInteger phiInverse = phi.modInverse(N);
BigInteger result = b.multiply(phiInverse).mod(N);
```